# How to access intermediate node in xml using RapidXml

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to xml parsing and I am using RapidXml (as i learnt it is easy to get started and use). I have fair amount of knowledge in C++ so using them together.

I have a xml file which in the format below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root-tag xmlns:xsi="" xmlns:xsd="" schemaVersion="" xmlns="">
  <Level2 fileType="" version="" typesetVersion="">
    <Level31></Level31>
    <Level32></Level32>
  </Level2>
  <Level21 version="" typeVersion="">
    <Level34 xsi:type="" typeVersion="">
      <Level4 xsi:type="" typeVersion="">
        <Level5 xsi:type="">
          <Level61>xx</Level61>
          <Level62>xxx,xxx</Level62>
          <Level63></Level63>
          <Level64></Level64>
          <Level65 typeVersion="">
            <Level7></Level7>
          </Level65>
        </Level5>
      </Level4>
    </Level34>
  </Level21>
</Root-tag>
```

Is there a way to access value at level 6 or 7 directly?
Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Took a look at Rapid XML, while it does look very fast, it doesn't seem to implement XPath, which would allow you to directly access all level 6 and 7 nodes with a simple XPath expression like "//Level5/*".

Comment: so @WilliamWalseth do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest you consider Saxon, or other XML Parser, that let's you do this sort of thing with XPath.  XML Parsers are very fast, and are suitable for most applications.  See http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml

Comment: Ok thank you. I will check if that helps.